# getters, setters, and loops

Tags: java, loops, get, set

I have this program, I have been working on for a class that flips a coin and counts the number of heads/tails it lands on. I finally have it working properly, however I need to implement get and set. I have 3 coins, a nickel, a quarter, and a dime.  I must use the get set to give them values and create a loop that repeatedly flips the three coins. Every time it lands on head it adds the value of the specific coin to a pool (total) and the loop is supposed to end when it becomes equal or greater than a dollar.  This is my coin class, which is inheriting the methods (all of which work) of another class. The problem is, once I get and set the values to my private integers, how do I freely use them in the while loop I am creating so I can add them too the total? (I apologize for the incomplete loop, I am just becoming very lost) Thanks ahead of time for any help!

---

Ok so I have gotten rid of all the errors thanks to everyone's help! The problem now is that when I run the code, the loop just keeps going (That is what it seems like at least, because its not even printing the print statement after the loop) what am I doing wrong? Part of me wonders if it is not inheriting the flip method properly, but It is inheriting it from a class that already uses it in another program and it works fine.

```
public class Coin extends GenericCoin {

    private int Dime;
    private int Nickel;
    private int Quarter;

    public Coin() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getDime() {
        return Dime;
    }

    public void setDime(int dime) {
        this.Dime = 10;
    }

    public int getNickel() {
        return Nickel;
    }

    public void setNickel(int nickel) {
        Nickel = 5;
    }

    public int getQuarter() {
        return Quarter;
    }

    public void setQuarter(int quarter) {
        Quarter = 25;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total = 0;

        Coin dime = new Coin();
        Coin nickel = new Coin();
        Coin quarter = new Coin();

        int d = dime.getDime();
        int n = nickel.getNickel();
        int q = quarter.getQuarter();


        while(total < 100) {//loop that will flip the 3 coins and add to total
            dime.flip();

            if(dime.headFlip1()) {
                total = total + d;
            }

            nickel.flip();
            if(nickel.headFlip2()) {
                total = total + n;
            }
            quarter.flip();
            if(quarter.headFlip3()){
                total = total + q;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(total + ".00");          
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing it right. Write similar head checks for nickel and quarter. And call the setters before you start with the `while` loop.

Comment: What language is this? You should add the language as one of the tags, so that people know what is going on.

Comment: I'm very happy to hear that I am on the right track. That is part of the problem, I am not too sure how to call the setters and then use them freely. I will look into it.

Comment: Also the language is Java, thanks for pointing that out! i will edit it so it clarifies

Comment: @Mrggg Just call them like any other method.

Comment: (Unrelated, but while I can understand no downvotes, I barely understand two upvotes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not called the Setter methods. Unless you call them, the values for `Dime`, `Nickel` and `Quarter` would remain uninitialized and therefore you wouldn't really be adding the values that you want to. So consider calling them before you start the loop.

Secondly, a **setter** function is used to **set the value passed to it**. For example, when you pass `quarter` to `setQuarter()`, the usual practice is to initialize the member variable `Quarter` with the value in the variable `quarter`. Effectively, your setter function would be something like this:

```
public void setQuarter(int quarter) {
    Quarter = quarter;
}
```

and the call to this method from your `main()` function would be

```
quarter.setQuarter(25);
```

Also, I am assuming you have the definitions of `headFlip1()`,`headFlip2()` and `headFlip3()`, though they do not appear in the snippet.

Comment: Ah ok I get it now, is there a particular reason why its done that way? I am new to java (taking it for a class) and its very different from the little bit of python I have taught myself.  And yes, my headFlip classes are defined in a different class this is inheriting from. They are different booleans however I have just discovered problems with them hat I need to fix haha But thanks you totally helped e figure out how to get the gets/sets to work properly!

Comment: It is done that way so that you can set different values for different objects. For example, you could use the setter to set different values of a nickel if you made objects for different countries.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should call the setter methods on each of the coins, which will initialize them. By default, the instance variables of a class get value 0 (for integers). Or better, use constructors to directly initialize objects if you are hardcoding them.

Second, the `total++ Dime` is a wrong syntax. `total++` in itself is a complete sentence which should end with a semicolon, eg. total ++;

You want to add the specific value of the Dime to the total. Then you should do

```
total = total + CoinObject.getDime(); or 
total += CoinObject.getDime();
```

`total++` just increments the value of total variable by one, 
e.g. if `total = 0`, then doing total++ sets it to 1.

Comment: Thanks abhishek for those edits. I didn't know how to add code snippets in my answer. This was my first post.